# Synapse crashes on 17.10 with Wayland

Tags: 17.10, wayland, synapse

Synapse won't start at all:

```
synapse 
[INFO 10:15:46.815109] [synapse-main:266] Starting up...
[INFO 10:15:46.922925] [synapse-main:208] Binding activation to <Control>space
Segmentation Fault
```

Everything's ok with Ubuntu with Xorg and Unity.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check the location of the displays you have available:

```
cd /tmp/.X11-unix && for x in X*; do echo ":${x#X}"; done
```

then, from the locations listed, try using any as arguments to the `--display` option.

For me, `synapse --display=:0` worked just fine.

NB: This allows you to manually launch synapse. However, you MAY want to ensure that:

When you start synapse from the application menu it launches with the options you desire.

append `--display=:0` to the end of `Exec=synapse` in the file `/usr/share/applications/synapse.desktop`.

You WILL need sudo access to do this. Be mindful of the space in the string you will be appending.

If it’s autostarted from your startup it is launched with the options you desire.

ensure you have GNOME Tweak Tool installed. Install it using `sudo apt install gnome-tweak-tool` or install it from the Software application.

Then navigate: Tweak Tool>Startup Applications>➕. Search for Synapse then click "Add".

Navigate Settings>Keyboard>➕. Enter Name: "Synapse", Command: "synapse --display=:0", Shortcut: [Whatever keyboard shortcut you desire].

This should suffice as a solution until a patch is made.

Comment: "sudo dnf install gnome-tweak-tool" you running fedora much ? No worries I run Fedodra as well. Probably change this to `sudo apt install gnome-tweak-tool` , may need to `sudo apt update` first as apt does not automatically update the way dnf does.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, it helped. But perhaps you can elaborate a little on what exactly it does and why it helps? It seems that this error appeared out of nowhere for me without any changes on my side (new packages, anything)

Comment: @alexisrozhkov there is a thread on this bug within the official synapse bugtracker. one of the answers describes this process and how it was found to be a solution: https://bugs.launchpad.net/synapse-project/+bug/1592008